# Laguerre polynomial problem

Tags: laguerre-polynomials

It is known that

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}z^nL_n(x)=\frac{1}{1-z}e^{-xz/(1-z)}$

where $L_n(x)$ is the Laguerre polynomial.

It there any neat way of expressing the following term:

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}z^{n+m}L_{n+m}(x)$

where the index of the Laguerre polynomial and $z$ become $(n+m)$, and $m$ is a given integer?

Comment: You have to specify what you need. What do you mean by: 'what to deal with'? Do you want a closed expression? Because if not the answer would be the formula you have given above subtracted by the terms till m.

Comment: Yes, a closed expression, or some related references for getting the closed expression of this series.